# Ef core include for many-to-many in the generic repository

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I have many-to-many relationship in the DB.
Typical realization with the eager loading in **EF Core** of GetAll method is:

```
    dbContext
    .DbSet<Book>
    .Include(e => e.BooksAuthors)
    .ThenInclude(ba => ba.Author)
```

But in case of generic repository I pass `params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes` as a parametr to the GetAll.

But the problem is, that with the help of

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> query,
   params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
            where T : class
        {
            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes.Aggregate(query,
                    (current, include) => current.Include(include));
            }

            return query;
        }
```

I can load only BooksAuthors, not the next level of nesting. How to pass ThenInclude as a parametr?

Comment: Don't use the "generic" repository **anti**pattern. A DbSet is already a repository, a DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work. A DbContext is neither a connection nor a model of the entire database. *Don't* call `DbSet<>()` directly, all you need to do is configure your DbContext properly and let it do its job.

Comment: Read Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) to understand just how bad a "generic" repository can be and Oren Eini's [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton). Oren Eini was the maintainer of NHibernate at the time. A DbContext's entities *are* the aggregate roots of a DDD bounded context. A DbContext should match a DDD bounded context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string version of include

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> query,
   params string[] includes)
            where T : class
        {
            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes.Aggregate(query,
                    (current, include) => current.Include(include));
            }

            return query;
        }
```

and your include would be

```
dbContext.DbSet<Book>.IncludeMultiple("BooksAuthors.Author")
```